# Best way to share and sell new CVT design?

Tags: hydraulics, transmission

What is the best way to sell an unpatented CVT design? It is hydraulic/direct drive design, and can function as a clutch mechanism.  I am just one person, and not capable or inclined to build it myself, and i am not interested in filing a provisional patent app myself (at least, not until the design is validated as being desireable and mechanically sound).
It has been sitting in the back of my mind for 15 years, and i have forgotten some of the advanced features.  The basic machine is still there, and i can re-engineer (re-imagine) the whole device if there is a good reason to.
I apologize if this is not the best forum to ask this question.  I've gotten bored with the cryptography board (cryptographic discoveries, totally separate), since those ideas have met resistance.
Thanks.

Comment: It might not be wise to wait for final design to file for patent. Consult a patent lawyer. They can assist for doing search for existing patents and help draft the patent so as to encompass your idea as well as possible improvements (since your design is not final yet) while ensuring that application is not rejected due to prior art.

Comment: With suitable modifications, this questions might be suited for law SE or a business/finance related SE.

Comment: Thanks for advice.  I was thinking more aling the lines of non-disclosure agreement with an interested company, and let them handle patent part.  Only problem is how to get an interested party without showing them something.  May have to do provisional,  in that case.

Comment: @Zekchelovek - also you probably know but just to make sure. Once you file a provisional, at least in the US, you have a fixed 1 year deadline to file the real patent application

Comment: possibly a question for https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/ too. Actually I think it's an interesting subject with a lot to discuss, but is as much about super-early-phase business strategy as it is about the patent-law aspects

Answer (score 1):

Critical CAVEAT: If you disclose it (without an NDA), or offer to sell it (without an NDA), then you will lose the right to patent it. Furthermore, while this should in theory prevent another party from patenting it, in practice, it might not. So you might get locked out of your own invention. The system is pretty unforgiving in this regard.

Comment: Thank you for feedback.  I do realize the provisional limits, having filed a couple times before.  I may try selling the NDA on ebay, with completion of NDA gaining access to invention for buyer.  That probably is a better question for legal board.